# Firebase Array not Rendering in AngularJS View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

What is stopping my view from being rendered after my "User" service is updated with the information necessary to view?

**Pseudocode:**

> 1. User signs in and the *profile.uid* information should be set. The *profile.uid* is later used as a child in my Firebase path.

```
    .factory('User', function (FirebaseUrl, $firebaseArray) {
        var o = {};

        o.setUser = function(authData) {
             o.profile.uid = authData.uid;
        }
        o.getProfile = function() {
            return o.profile;
        }
        return o;
    }
```

> 2. Using $state.go('view') with Angular UI-Router I go to the following view:

Controller:

```
.controller('viewCtrl', function ($scope, User, $firebaseArray, FirebaseUrl) {

    var profile = User.getProfile();

    //if I hardcore "facebook:213032130516" in the .child(), everything renders correctly...

    var messagesRef = new Firebase(FirebaseUrl + 'user_meta/').child(profile.uid);
    var query = messagesRef.orderByChild("timestamp").limitToLast(5);

    $scope.list = $firebaseArray(query);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="dog in list">
     <h2> {{dog.key}}</h2>
</div>
```

As it stands currently, the view doesn't render. No errors are logged, just the view is blank. As per the comment in the controller code, when I hardcode the *.child(profile.uid)*, so it becomes *.child('facebook:112351)*, the view renders correctly.

Can someone help me with a better solution to implement, and ultimately, why this is not working?

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing here calls `setUser()`, so `getProfile()` can't work. There are also various other syntax errors in the code. Instead of providing pseudo-code, try to isolate the problem in a jsfiddle/jsbin and then provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) based on that here. That was we get the complete (but minimal) code and we can look at the jsfiddle/jsbin to see it in action. The easier you make it for us to help, the more likely you are to get useful help.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I will do as soon as possible. Aka tomorrow when I can get to my computer. Thanks guys.

Comment: Frank, I couldn't replicate the behavior when making the MCVE. Instead, I found this was resolved when I cold started my entire application from command line, that the code works as it should (ie. _>ionic serve_). However if I call the function without restarting, or while I'm working on my code it doesn't operate correctly. For the time being I'm assuming it's a small bug in the production environment that will be difficult to reproduce in the mobile environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to be 100% sure by just looking at this two pieces of code, but I would assume that you don't pass the data when you call setUser somewhere else. Try to log it out and see where you lose it. Do you have a github repo of this project that we could look at?

Comment: I will do this as soon as possible. It might take me a bit to figure it out (I'm a noob), but yeah I'll try to get you the information asap. I'm thinking it has something to do with not having an $apply or $digest  loop in and the view not re-rendering

Comment: I don't think the problem is with $apply or $digest. Since it works with hard-coded data it is safe to assume that the problem is setUser function or before it.

Comment: Max, I couldn't replicate the behavior when making the MCVE. Instead, I found this was resolved when I cold started my entire application from command line, that the code works as it should (ie. >ionic serve). However if I call the function without restarting, or while I'm working on my code it doesn't operate correctly. For the time being I'm assuming it's a small bug in the production environment that will be difficult to reproduce in the mobile environment

Answer (score 1):

you have an undefined `authData` in your user factory.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited it accordingly. authData is provided from a function inside my userFactory. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: are you initalizing `profile.uid` prior to this view? do you get an array at all? try to add `$scope.list.$loaded(console.log)` to help yourself debug.

Comment: It is being initialize, I'm just not sure if it's before the view is being rendered. Seeing that my profile information is being updated in the factory, I'm wondering if/how to apply an $apply when that occurs. Perhaps that view is already rendered behind the scene at my login screen?

Comment: Are you using `ui-router`? if you are it is worth mentioning **resolve** parameter when you define states.

Comment: No I am not @Muli Yulzary. I wanted to figure out if there's a way to do it without resolve. Is this possible? Only reason being, I would like to have an  _if_ based statement which uses parameters available in the controller; something I don't believe you can do with **resolve**.

Comment: that depends on the parameters. are they bound to the scope? if they are then you are correct.